# Two anti-derivatives of $\int \frac{du}{1-\frac{1}{2}u}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms

WolframAlpha computes $\int \frac{du}{1-\frac{1}{2}u}$ to be $-2\cdot\log(u-2)$. Computing derivative of this result confirms its correctness. However, I manually obtained the result $-2\log(1-\frac{1}{2}u)$. Computing that derivative also yields $1-\frac{1}{2}u$:

$$
\frac{d}{dy}-2 \big(\log  (y-2)\big)=-\frac{2}{y-2} \\
\frac{d}{dy}-2 \left(\log  \left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)=-\frac{2}{y-2}
$$

When I order WolframAlpha to compute difference of $-2 \big(\log  (y-2)\big)$ and $-2 \left(\log  \left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)$ then it seems to be non-zero, somewhere around $1.428$. What is happening here?

Comment: $C$ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: I agree, but how can you write such a short comment?

Comment: Because comments count literal symbols so even mathjax ones count what you have are spaces in those dollar signs...counting as symbols including the dollar signs

Comment: @flawr By adding something like `$\text{}$` to the end of it.

Comment: @Kaster. It is the second time on this site where I see a good answer using a single character !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may recall that
$$
\int f(x) \:dx
$$ is defined *up to a constant term*.

The two antiderivatives agree up to a constant term:
$$
-2 \big(\log  (y-2)\big)=-2 \left(\log  \left(1-\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)+\color{red}{C}.
$$ Observe that a general antiderivative is

> $$
> -2\log  |y-2|+\color{red}{C}.
> $$

Comment: Why distinct one of derivatives as the "general" one?

Comment: $y \mapsto \log  |y-2|$ is general because it is defined both as $y<2$ and as $y>2$ which is not the case of $y \mapsto \log  (y-2)$. One may recall that, dealing with real numbers, the argument of $\log$ has to be positive.

Comment: This always puzzles me, I would write y-limiting condition "y-2 > 0" rather than wrapping "y-2" with absolute value